# Server tag in OnClientClick

Tags: asp.net

The following gives me an error of "The server tag is not well formed"

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete <%# Eval("Username") %>?');">
    Delete
</asp:LinkButton>
```

(This is used in a data bound ListView that displays a list of users. When you click the delete button a JavaScript confirm dialog is used to ask you if you're sure)

So, how can I embed a server tag in a string that contains JavaScript?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is the binding nugget and the use of single and double quotes.

```
<asp:LinkButton D="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick='<%# CreateConfirmation(Eval("Username")) %>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then on the code-behind add the function...

```
Public Function CreateConfirmation(ByVal Username As String) As String
    Return String.Format("return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete {0}?');", Username)
End Function
```

When the binding nugget is used as the value for an attribute, you'll note you have to use single quotes. Your script also needed quotes for the embedded string parameter to the confirm function. You basically ran out of quotes.

Comment: Note that CreateConfirmation(Eval("Username")) should be written CreateConfirmation((string)Eval("Username"))

(I'm using C#...might be that VB.NET automatically casts the object returned from Eval)

Comment: If you're using C#, you could just make the 'Username' parameter type object opposed to string, and you wouldn't need the cast

Answer (score 7):

I found this answer over at www.asp.net

```
OnClientClick='<%# Eval("ProductName", "return confirm(""Delete the Product {0}?"")" ) %>'
```

This puts everything in the markup so anyone doing maintenance later doesn't have dig around to find all of the pieces.

Comment: This is almost correct. Either OnClientClick='<%# Eval("ProductName", @"return confirm(""Delete the Product {0}?"")" ) %>' or OnClientClick='<%# Eval("ProductName", "return confirm(\"Delete the Product {0}?\")" ) %>' worked for me; basically the inner-most double-quote is a double-quote in a C# string and should be escaped accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Add the code dynamically in the ItemDataBound event for the ListView control.

In your page_Load event add the following

```
lst.ItemDataBound += new EventHandler<ListViewItemEventArgs>(lst_ItemDataBound);
```

Then in your ItemDataBound event handler add

```
Control DeleteButton = e.Item.FindControl("DeleteButton");
DeleteButton.OnClientClick = string.Format( "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete '{0}'?", Username);
```

This solution should work whether you use OnClientClick or Sachin Gaur's solution.

Comment: Sadly I cannot do this - as this control is part of a databound ListView

Comment: @Richard E-If I understand you correctly it should be in your 'e' parameter.

Comment: @Richard E-I've adjusted the answer to help you find your button.  I think we deserve our down vote to be removed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the onclick event at run time, like this:

```
DeleteButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "'return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete '" + Username);
```

Comment: If you have a server side event for this button, I believe this strategy will add 'onclick' to the HTML element twice, causing unexpected behaviour.

Comment: No it won't add. A server side event will have some __dpPostBack... call. You can add the attribute and view the page source.

Comment: Sadly I cannot do this - as this control is part of a databound ListView

Comment: My mistake.  ... sorry, I'm positive I've had this issue in the past.  I guess I did not make the correct distinction.

Comment: I think, You can do this in the List Bound event as we have the RowDataBound event for GridView.