# Why < is getting converted as &lt; during runtime

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am trying to write an aspx page where I am passing some server side value to the Javascript. The server side tag is changing from `<%` to `&lt;%`

```
<asp:TextBox
    ID="txtOriginalNo"
    runat="server"
    onkeyup="javascript:EnterKeyPress(<%=ibtnSubmit.ClientID%>,event);"
    TabIndex="1"
    MaxLength="13"
></asp:TextBox>
```

This is getting converted during runtime to:

```
<input
    name="txtOriginalNo"
    type="text"
    maxlength="13"
    id="txtOriginalNo"
    tabindex="1"
    onkeyup="javascript:EnterKeyPress(&lt;%=ibtnSubmit.ClientID%>,event);"
/>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a server tag inside a server control. Set the property from code behind:

```
txtOriginalNo.Attributes["onkeyup"] = "EnterKeyPress(" + ibtnSubmit.ClientID + ",event);"
```

Note: Don't use the `javascript:` protocol in event attributes. It's used when you put Javascript code in an URL, if you use it in an event attribute it becomes a label instead.

Comment: Thanks Guffa.. Breaking my head from morning. it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `<%= %>` there, inside an attribute of a server-side control. You need to assign the `asp:TextBox`'s `onkeyup` property differently, something like:

```
<% myTextBox.OnKeyUp = "javascript:EnterKeyPress(ibtnSubmit.ClientID)"; %>
```

Comment: Where should i add this Keyup? should it be in Markup or in the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

It gets converted to protect you from XSS (cross-site scripting) vulnerabilities. It is a good thing. You cannot have most types of server tags inside attributes of server tags in ASP.NET.

However, you can use binding, see this question [528006 (Server tag in OnClientClick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528066/server-tag-in-onclientclick) for more info:

```
<asp:TextBox onkeyup="<%# CreateKeypressEvent(Eval(ibtnSubmit.ClientID)) %>">
</asp:TextBox>

protected static CreateKeyPressEvent(string source)
{
    return "javascript:EnterKeyPress('" + source + "', event);";
}
```