# Syntax error in dynamic aspx Javascript function call?

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm writing a bit of aspx code to call a JavaScript function from a server control.  Here's the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkInfoPortalUnpin(portalareaid) {
        if(portalareaid == 1) {
            alert('a message');
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here's the calling aspx code:

```
<asp:ImageButton OtherFields="omitted..."
   OnClientClick='checkInfoPortalUnpin(<%# Eval("PortalAreaID") %>);' />
```

When I view the source of that line in the browser (IE8) it is rendering as this:

```
... onclick="checkInfoPortalUnpin(&lt;%# Eval(&quot;PortalAreaID&quot;) %>);"
```

and I get a syntax error when I click on the ImageButton.  I know the OnClientClick does work because if I replace the <%# ... %> with a hard-coded '1' the function runs fine.  Am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528066/server-tag-in-onclientclick


Cheers.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203200/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-asp-net-button-click-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

`... OnClientClick="checkInfoPortalUnpin('<%# Eval(\"PortalAreaID\") %>');" ...`

Comment: That doesn't work because the " is used inside the main set of ". It gives a "Server tag is not well formed" error.

Comment: You're saying that this does not work:  `<asp:ImageButton otherFields="omitted..." OnClientClick="checkInfoPortalUnpin('<%# Eval(\"PortalAreaID\") %>');' />` ?

Comment: What you've posted now might work, now you've put the \" in.  Before the edit there were no escape characters.

Comment: yep, agree. i missed the extra " in context.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" OnClientClick="checkInfoPortalUnpin('<%# Eval(\"PortalAreaID\") %>');" />
```

You forget to put single quote outside the server tag.